Help message "You <em>cannot</em> use Markdown here" cannot be translated
One of the help messages when posting a question cannot be translated.
It is the string below for help on using HTML.
<pre>
    You <em>cannot</em> use Markdown here
</pre>

Screenshot
(Spanish version of Stack Overflow)



Similar strings
The strings below are similar but different from the ones above. These are translatable.
<pre>
    You can <em>not</em> use Markdown in here.
</pre>

You can $em$not$endem$ use Markdown in here.

